# Defining an ultrafilter on primes

Tags: abstract-algebra, model-theory

My main corollary is:

> For each non-principal ultrafilter F on the set of primes:
>
> $\prod (\mathbb Z/(p^n))\cong \prod (\mathbb F_p[T]/(T^n)) $

I know that the above is correct because due to the baby ax-kochen principle:

> the $(\mathbb Z/(p^n))$ and $(\mathbb F_p[T]/(T^n))$ are elementarily equivalent

And by the kiesler and shellah theorem:

> any two L-structure $M$ and $N$ are elementarily equivalent if there exists an index $st I$ and and ultrafilter $D$ such that $\prod M/D \cong \prod N/D$

My question is how do I define the ultrafilter on primes?

Should I define it on prime ideal or prime numbers?

Comment: This is very clearly done in the context of $\Bbb Z$, where the prime numbers are exactly those generating prime ideals. I'm not sure what you're trying to ask. In general (ultra)filters are defined on a given set. Here it is the set of primes. There's not subtlety to this statement, no hidden meanings. It is what it says it is.

Comment: @AsafKaragila thanks for your answer I want to know how we define a filter let I be a set of all prime numbers then what is the power set of I respectfully what is the $D\subset I$ which we call D a filter, what is the structure of D?

Comment: Do you know how to show that there exists a non-principal ultrafilter on $\mathbb{N}$ or any other infinite set?

Comment: @AlexKruckman yes buy it would be very kind of you if you explain them to me again because I think I didn't quit get it